# É possivel usar bibliotecas dentro da estrutura do projeto java?

Tags: java, aplicação-web, tomcat, caminho-relativo

A minha dúvida é a seguinte, eu consigo por meio de caminho relativo linkar meu .JSP até uma biblioteca dentro do diretório do projeto? Ou somente no diretório do servidor: Webapps, etc?

No momento, quando eu quero mostrar uma imagem no meu sistema, eu faço o seguinte:

```
<img src="http://localhost:8080/minhaLogo.png" width=30>
```

Que se encontra no diretório:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\ROOT\minhaLogo.png
```

Tudo que está abaixo do webapps/root é de fácil acesso.

> Porém, eu gostaria de utilizar a logo dentro de um caminho relativo da minha estrutura de pastas do projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tentei isso de varias formas, mas não tive sucesso, por mais que o console diga que eu tive um `HTTP GET 200` á imagem não carrega. **É possível fazer isso o que eu estou tentando fazer?**

Eu tentei algo do tipo, com diversas variações de diretório, mas nenhum sucesso:

```
<img src="<%= request.getContextPath() + "/newLib/minhaLogo.png" %>" width=30>
```

Muito Obrigado.

***EDIT:***

Como é uma pagina de teste, é simplesmente uma pagina com a imagem no body:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>teste link relativo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="bt"><img src="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/newLib/minhaLogo.png" width=30></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Testa com o código abaixo e verifica se resolve.

```
<img src="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/newLib/minhaLogo.png" width=30>
```

Comment: vou testar, obrigado

Comment: apesar da tag ficar certo no F12 <img width="30" src="/QualidadeWeb_novo_10-08-18/newLib/minhaLogo.png"> e retornar uma "HTTP GET 200", a imagem não aparece

Comment: Poderia enviar o código da página que você usa essa imagem?

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o código, mas como é apenas uma página de teste, não tem muita coisa não :/

Comment: Testei seu código e funciona perfeitamente relacionado a tag img. Não tem nada de errado para não mostrar a imagem na tela.

Comment: Eu achei que tinha algo a ver com a rede da minha empresa, então fiz a mesma coisa no meu computador pessoal e nada